# Hide a div when user is logged in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a parameter to find out whether there is any user currently logged in or not, namely current_user. If it is 'nil' then no user is logged in or otherwise. so i want to hide the login button when current_user is not equal to 'nil'. any suggestions?

```html
<div ng-click="login_popup()">
         
         <a style="color: #fff;padding: 5px 10px;font-weight: 600;background: #00bfa9;text-transform: uppercase;margin: 10px;font-size: 15px;cursor: pointer;display: block;float: right;">
              Login
            </a>
         </div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please read the SO posting guidelines. Post your current code, and show what you've tried/looked into.

Comment: Show us your mark-up

Comment: use `ng-hide="current_user"`

Comment: sorry for that. Updated it.

Comment: In this case I wouldn't hide the `<a>`, in case your div is styled in a way which makes it still 'clickable'. i.e. if there's a user logged in, they can still launch the login popup.

Answer (score 2):

[ng-hide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide)

> When the ngHide expression evaluates to a truthy value then the .ng-hide CSS class is added to the class attribute on the element causing it to become hidden. When falsy, the .ng-hide CSS class is removed from the element causing the element not to appear hidden.

```
<button ng-hide="current_user">login</button>
```